# How to query firebase for many to many relationship?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, firebase-realtime-database

It is my first time developing a SPA, and I am not using JS frameworks like React, Vue or Angular. My project just uses the firebase sdk and jquery to access the DOM elements.

In my app, the users can be associated with projects. Since that, I have a `user-projects` and `project-users` paths to represent that relationship.

When a user logs in my app I request `users/uid` to get the user data. After that I have to fetch the projects associated with the user. I will take the ids of the associated projects to finally request the data of each project.

I'm trying to use promises as described [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html), but I get nothing in the console.

```
function loadUserProjects() {
    // Authenticated user
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    // General reference to the real time db
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();

    // Request the user data
    ref.child('users/'+user.uid).on('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var user_data = snapshot.val(); console.log(user_data);

        // Global variable to store the id of the selected project
        project_selected_key = user_data.project_selected;

        // Get the list of associated projects
        return ref.child('user-projects/'+user.uid).on('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot);
            return snapshot;
        });
    }).then(function (projectsSnapshot) {
        console.log(projectsSnapshot);

        // List associated projects
        var project_options = '';
        projectsSnapshot.forEach(function (e) {
            project_options += '<option value="'+e.key+'">'+e.val()+'</option>';
        });
        if (! project_options) {
            project_options = '<option disabled selected value>- Ningún proyecto -</option>';
        }

        $('#project_selected').html(project_options);
    }, function(error) {
        // Something went wrong.
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

I know that I have to use one additional request, because at this point the `<select>`will be populated with `true`values (the additional request have to query the full data of each project). But I am not getting messages in the console.

Thanks in advance.

*After that, I need to define different levels of privilege in each project, and associate a level when a project is assigned to a specific user. Initially I was very excited about the real time, but it seems that firebase is getting more complicated than I supposed.*

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase `on()` listener can respond to multiple events. A promise can only resolve once, that's why it's only available when you use Firebase's `once()` operation.

```
return ref.child('user-projects/'+user.uid).once('value');
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have the project keys in an array ```project_keys```. Using ```ref.child('projects/'+project_keys[i]).once('value')``` I can get the project data for one project. How I can use the array to get all in one request?